# Converting selects with onchange to ul and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, drop-down-menu

I am trying to convert my select boxes into more stylish ul dropdowns but the selects are using onchange that calls a function with document.search.submit() in it

I thought this was a good option for my purpose because I figured I could just hide the real selects and the dropdown would change that value as well and submit the form but that does not work. what can I do to submit these values into a url argument.

note the options in the selects are dynamically generated in python

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
  createDropDown(); 

  $(".dropdown dt a").click(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var dropID = $(this).closest("dl").attr("id"); 
    $("#" + dropID).find("ul").toggle(); 
  }); 

  $(document).bind('click', function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target); 
    if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) 
      $(".dropdown dd ul").hide(); 
  }); 


  $(".dropdown dd ul a").click(function() { 
    var dl = $(this).closest("dl"); 
    var dropID = dl.attr("id"); 
    var text = $(this).html(); 
    var source = dl.prev(); 
    $("#" + dropID + " dt a").html(text); 
    $("#" + dropID + " dd ul").hide(); 
    source.val($(this).find("span.value").html()) 
  }); 
}); 

function createDropDown() { 
  var selects = $("select.dropdown_value"); 
  var idCounter = 1; 
  selects.each(function() { 
    var dropID = "dropdown_" + idCounter; 
    var source = $(this); 
    var selected = source.find("option[selected]"); 
    var options = $("option", source); 
    source.after('<dl id="' + dropID + '" class="dropdown"></dl>'); 
    $("#" + dropID).append('<dt><a href="#">' + selected.text() + '<span class="value">' + selected.val() + '</span></a></dt>'); 
    $("#" + dropID).append('<dd><ul></ul></dd>'); 
    options.each(function() { 
      $("#" + dropID + " dd ul").append('<li><a href="#">' + $(this).text() + '<span class="value">' + $(this).val() + '</span></a></li>'); 
    }); 
    idCounter++; 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Great! it worked immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it just added the document.search.submit() function into the bottom of the click function, any optimizations of this code are welcome still thank you